# How to dereference a double pointer for inet_ntop

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, double-pointer

I am trying to print out the address using `inet_ntop`. I have a struct within a struct

```
struct random_struct {
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
}

void do_some_stuff(random_struct **arg1) {
    (*arg1)->myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET
    char buffer[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop((*arg1)->myaddr.sin_family, (*arg1)->&myaddr.sin_addr), buffer, sizeof(buffer)) 
}
```

I receive the compilation error

```
expected identifier before ‘&’ token
  inet_ntop((*arg1)->myaddr.sin_family,(*arg1)->&myaddr.sin_addr, buffer, sizeof(buffer))
```

I know this argument is incorrect

```
(*arg1)->&myaddr.sin_addr
```

What should the correct syntax be? I would like to keep passing in the double pointer into `void do_some_stuff`

Comment: What about `&((*arg1)->myaddr.sin_addr)`

Comment: If i use that them I get the compilation error `called object is not a function or function pointer`

Comment: Disregard my last statement. I forgot to put a semicolon at the end. It compiles now.

Comment: _Side note_: Unless you intend to change `arg1` inside `do_some_stuff` there's no need for a double star pointer. Just do: `random_struct *arg1` and use `arg1->whatever`